# What is the difference between COUNT(*) and COUNT(table.ColumnName)?

Tags: sql, database

What is the difference between COUNT(*) and COUNT(table.ColumnName)?

I always thought that it is faster to put a column name as a parameter for `COUNT`, but now when I think of it I really don't know because `*` means that the function counts rows, so probably there isn't any difference? Or maybe giving a specific column name even slows the process?

Comment: Read performance [COUNT(*) vs COUNT(col)](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference between these two is not (primarily) performance. They count different things:

`COUNT(*)` counts the rows in your table.

`COUNT(column)` counts the entries in a column - ignoring `null` values.

Of course there will be performance differences between these two, but that is to be expected if they are doing different things. Especially when the column allows `null`-values, the query will take longer than on a column that does not (or `COUNT(*)`).

Answer (score 4):

`COUNT(*)` returns a count of all records

`COUNT(table.ColumnName)` returns a count of all non-null values.

---

See Microsoft documentation:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx

> **ALL**
>
> Applies the aggregate function to all values. ALL is the default.
>
> **DISTINCT**
>
> Specifies that COUNT returns the number of unique nonnull
>   values.